I can accept my own answer without waiting for 48 hours. If I retract the accept vote, it shows an error message
I accidentally accepted my own answer at The “View all” community buttons in the Community user's site profiles link to a server error page.
When I accepted my own answer, I was shocked.
Here it says we need to wait 2 days from the time we originally asked the question before we can accept our own answer. But now I have successfully accepted my own answer before that period ended.
When I want to retract my accept vote, it gives me an error message again:

User has already voted this way. Undo the vote, or change the vote to continue.

The point is, I cannot unaccept my own answer!
I know there  is an existing question about the same error but that one occurs when trying to unfollow: Error message “User has already voted this way. Undo the vote, or change the vote to continue” when unfollowing posts.

Not only my answer, but I can’t retract my accept vote in any question I asked.

Most likely same root cause as this one, something is broken in the backend, big time.

Same as this one which is resolved as of 2 minutes ago. Sorry, folks!
